# skypeforlinux 8.13.0.2 fails to start on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: skype

Updating my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS today also installed a new skypeforlinux 8.13.0.2 replacing 8.11.0.4.

skypeforlinux 8.13.0.2 does not start, I just get a blank with a menu bar. The menu entries are selectable, but nothing appears to happen.

Starting the new skypeforlinux from the command line does not produce any output in the terminal window.

Comment: Same here except that sometimes after logging in, I do see my normal chat overview in a blink before the window turns all white. Switching back to 8.11.0.4 works for me.

Comment: Same here on Linux Mint 17.1 as well (based on Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Maybe worth watching the [official forum here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/upgraded-to-the-latest-skype-linux-version-but/34553112-f42c-4740-a435-a64ddf3ad89f), as many people having the same problem (check the last page).

Comment: Just to note, a new version just came out today, 8.14.0.10. However, it still does not work for me, I wonder if anyone got lucky with that...

Comment: And still broken in 8.15.0.4 as well.

Answer (score 7):

Use old package:

```
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux=8.11.0.4
```

Thanks to @Sleeper9 for pointing to [official forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/upgraded-to-the-latest-skype-linux-version-but/34553112-f42c-4740-a435-a64ddf3ad89f).

Update from @Sleeper9: `8.16.0.4` also works.

Comment: Sadly, I do not have enough rep to post a new answer, but finally, the latest 8.16.0.4 version solved the problem. Try to update now, and see if it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms with Skype 8.75 running on a Dell XPS13 7390, it looks like there was a problem detecting which video driver to use (that machine has a Intel UHD Coffee Lake), so I fixed it by running:

`LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=iHD skypeforlinux`

Answer (score -1):

If you run the newest `skypeforlinux` (as normal user) in `/usr/bin/skypeforlinux` in terminal, nothing happens.
i.e. no output.

If you run it in `/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux`, you get a Segmentation fault.

But an interesting solution is to run it with `sudo`, then you can work with it.

```
sudo /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux
```

and it should run.

I have also deleted my `.skypeforlinux` in my home folder. Interestingly you run it as root, but the config are written correctly. Looks like some coding error.

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10 GNOME Shell

Comment: Running proprietary application as root is not secure. It is bad idea.